# Type hint for python module

Tags: python

How to type hint a module as variable

File `bun.py`

```
class Bun:
   # few class variables having word bun
   bunny
```

File `letter_service.py`

```
import pkg.sub_pkg.bun as b

class LetterService:
   A: ?? = a 
   B: ?? = b
```

I tried using `ModuleType` and `Any`. But problem with both is that on using say

File `app.py`

```
from pkg.sub_pkg.letter_service import LetterService

# Case-1 with type hints mentioned above
LetterService.B.   # On pressing dot after B, No Options displayed

# Case-2 without type hints 
LetterService.B.bunny   # On pressing dot after B, Options displayed
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Hi Kache, Thanks. I referred the same link earlier and used as `B: ModuleType = b` but this did not worked.